# Layout displacment on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I am using INTEL XDK(1995) and Ionics to build HTML 5 application for Android and iOS.

Application runs like it should on Android devices and also on my iPhone 4 which has iOS 7.1.1

Application requires internet connection to load location of data and data it self and is then placed on device screen.
Here is the example how application looks like:
[image: Normal layout]

And this is example from the iPhone 6 and iOS 8.3:
[image: iOS 8.3]

It looks like that height isn't calculated properly. But it's interesting that buttons are placed correctly. Because they are also set by the height of the screen. But on some other device which is also iPhone 6 and has iOS 8.3 works like it should. Anyone knows what could make a difference on same device?
Please say if you need any more information.

Comment: can u post some code

Comment: there is quite some code. I can post you code from index if you would like. I discovered that if I download cordova.js from this link: https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/tree/master/src and includ it instead: <script src="cordova.js"></script>.  Application will load with correct layout, but I coulden't remove status bar anymore.

Comment: You should not be replacing the cordova.js file in your app. The build system will place that into your app automatically, it is tightly-coupled to the build system and customized to the device OS and should not be part of your project directory!!

Comment: I know that, but for some reason that helped, but broke plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem. When I went to the client which had this problem, I discovered that splash screen didn't even show and instead it went directly to the application.
So I added init-dev.js file and called my starting AngularJS method from "ready" listener method.